# Sed from line 6 on from all txt files and being able to output all the results in a single file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I will be using awk
to do the following:
I need to sed from all *.txt files from line 6 until the end All the results should be in a new single file with the name of each file preceding the results

Example: Having different txt files the result should be one single that looks like this taking from the 3rd line to the end

```
file 1
3
4
5
file 2
3
4
5
file 3
3
4
5
```

Function which was suggested to me

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {print FILENAME}; FNR>=6' ./*.txt > output
```

my files look as follow original file:

```
file 1
1 
2
3
4
5
Done

file 2
1 
2
3
4
5
Done
```

file needed

```
file 1
2
3
4
5

file 2
2
3
4
5
6
```

while having an empty line in between and while removing the last line which is "done"

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME} FNR>1{print p} {p=$0}'
```

delayed printing, by default skips the last line

from n'th line forward, change `FNR>1` to `FNR>n`